# ¿Qué cambios han existido en las conjugaciones verbales?

Tags: verbos, historia, conjugación

La pregunta quizás es muy amplia, así que trataré de irme con 4 ejemplos que encontré para cerrar un poco.

En la definición de los verbos mover, volver, tener y estar, aparecen 3 de ellos (mover, tener y estar) como conjugación modelo *actual*, mientras que volver, aparece que la conjugación *actual* está basada en mover. Mi pregunta se remite al *actual*. ¿Desde cuando cambió la conjugación de estos verbos? ¿Cuál era su conjugación previa? Si acaso son cambios de una misma época (suponiendo que los 3 verbos hubieran cambiado en un congreso de ortografía del año de 19XX) ¿Qué otros verbos cambiaron al mismo tiempo que estos?

Para mayor facilidad, se puede dejar solo con los verbos de ejemplo y obviar la última pregunta, si lo expresan por chat o comentarios.

Comment: Creo que lo de "actual" se refiere a que es el modelo de conjugación que actualmente se sigue para otros verbos parecidos. No es que su conjugación haya variado en el pasado, sino que puede que anteriormente fuese otro el verbo modelo. En todo caso en el NTLLE veo que ningún diccionario incluye la marca de "conjugación modelo" o "conjugación como", así que si realmente queremos ver cómo han evolucionado los tiempos verbales lo vamos a tener que preguntar de forma más genérica y buscar las soluciones en las distintas gramáticas existentes.